# Непереводимая строка "Search Q&A"

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация

В строке поиска (верхний правый угол) написано "Search Q&A". Эта строка переведена на русский в Transifex, но не используется движком сайта.

[Tx:8301](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/$/73585182?key=3ffc82bf6b470fcbe0120ed23ec3c811)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Плюсаните этот вопрос на Meta SE, чтобы быстрее исправили: [The “Search Q&A” translation from Transifex is not used](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/274064/296059)

Comment: ура! исправили.

Comment: @NickVolynkin подскажите, плиз, как правильно ссылку на строку из Transifex получить.